# C# Generics

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to create an instance of a generic class, without knowing what type to cast it to it until runtime. I've written the following code

```
        Type pType = propertyInfo.GetType();
        ObjectComparer<pType> oc = new  ObjectComparer<pType>();
```

Hopefully that gives you an idea what I'm trying to do, however it wont compile it just says

"the type or namespace pType could not be found".

Is there any easy way of doing this?

Thanks

Gavin

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Type type = typeof(ObjectComparer<>).MakeGenericType(pType);
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

However, unless you cast to a non-generic interface (`IComparer`, maybe), you lose the ability to use it **as** a generic type.

---

The most common answer here is a non-generic base class/interface:

```
interface ISomeInterface {
    object SomeMethod(object value);
}
interface ISomeInterface<T> : ISomeInterface {
    T SomeMethod(T value);
}
```

You can then invoke via the non-generic `ISomeInterface` without having to jump through any extra hoops.

Example using `MakeGenericMethod` below - but a non-generic base interface would more efficient:

```
class Program {
    static void Main() {
        int i = 123;
        typeof(Program).GetMethod("Foo",
                BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .MakeGenericMethod(i.GetType())
            .Invoke(null, new object[] { i });
    }
    static void Foo<T>(T value) {
        ObjectComparer<T> comparer = new ObjectComparer<T>();
        comparer.Bar(value);
    }
}
class ObjectComparer<T> {
    public void Bar(T value) {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).Name + " = " + value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Am I right in thinking that code gets me an instance of the class as an object? If so how would I then cast it to the type of the class so I can call its methods?

Thanks

Comment: You can't (convenitently) - hence my comment about perhaps casting to a non-generic type (perhaps put your methods there?). You could perhaps call into a generic **method** and do the work there? (I'll add an example).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
Type someType = typeof(ObjectComparer<>);
Type toConstruct = someType.MakeGenericType (pType);

object o = Activator.CreateInstance (toConstruct);
```

Seems that i'm to slow.